# How to separate very close characters in binary image for OCR in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, imagefilter, binary-image

I made a basic OCR system in Matlab using correlation. (It's not a professional project, only as an exercise and I am not using the ocr() function of Matlab). My code is working almost correctly for clean text images. But if I make the job a little harder (taking the text photo for side position with angle) my code does not give good results. I use Principal Component Analysis for correct text alignment, but if I do this (taking photo with angle), the characters are very close together and I can't separate them for the recognizing process.

**Original Image and after preprocessing (adaptive thresholding, adjusting,PCA)**

[image: Original Image and after preprocessing (adaptive thresholding, adjusting,PCA)]

How can I separate the characters correctly?

Comment: Please provide your code, currently your question is off-topic.

Comment: @RobAu: seeing the code will not help. This is a question of method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I disagree. I think the problem might be in the preprocessing, and currently we have no way to see what was done.

Comment: (as can be seen the hole in the 'A' gets filled, so probably there is too much dilation going on, or the adaptive thresholding is not aggresive enough)

Comment: @RobAu: Touching characters is a common problem and adaptive thresholding is a good starting point. There is no magical method that will work for any case. I bet that adusting the threshold will make other parts of the characters disappear before the characters separate (which they might never do).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2636172/461499

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what Yves suggests is to erode the image. Which is implemented as `imerode` in matlab. Perhaps scale the image first (though it is not needed here)

e.g. with this code

```
ocr(imerode(I,strel('disk',3)))
```

where I is your "BOOLEAN" black-white image, I receive

```
ocrText with properties:
                  Text: 'BOOLEAN↵↵'
CharacterBoundingBoxes: [9×4 double]
  CharacterConfidences: [9×1 single]
                 Words: {'BOOLEAN'}
     WordBoundingBoxes: [14 36 208 43]
       WordConfidences: 0.5477
```